# Get; not working properly

Tags: c#, accessor

For a school assignment, I'm supposed to make a Time class that can store a time in hours, minutes and seconds. Everything is working fine, but the properties always return 0 when only declaring get; and set;

```
private int seconds, minutes, hours;
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
```

If I define what to return in the getter, it works properly:

```
private int seconds, minutes, hours;
    public int Seconds { get { return this.seconds; } set { this.seconds = value; } }
    public int Minutes { get { return this.minutes; } set { this.minutes = value; } }
    public int Hours { get { return this.hours; } set { this.hours = value; } }
```

I don't really mind writing this extra code, but to my understanding, the first piece of code should work just fine. What is going on here?

Comment: The first piece of code *does* work fine - if you set `Seconds` and then get `Seconds`, you'll get the same value back. It won't have anything to do with the `seconds` field though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you're showing isn't quite enough, but it does imply that you don't understand how [auto-properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384054(v=vs.140).aspx) work. They do not magically bind with your backing fields (`seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`) - they create their own.

So the only way to change the backing field is by using the setter - `Seconds = 42;`. I assume you're using `seconds = 42;` instead, which cannot possibly work; you're changing a completely separate field that has no connection to the `Seconds` property.

Comment: Well, that was a quick answer, thanks for explaining. I already thought it was weird that C# could magically link `Seconds` to `seconds`, but that's how it was explained to me, or maybe how I interpreted it.

Comment: @Connor It's entirely possible you misunderstood or misheard, or even that your teacher doesn't understand what they're teaching well enough (I've certainly seen many such teachers) - the key point is to look at confusion, and don't let go until you fully understand what is actually happening. Learn to love that feeling of confusion - it's what tells you there's something to learn :P

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, why do you have private int seconds, minutes, hours?

If you just try:

```
public int Seconds {get;set;}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Get is working, and it is returning you 0 that is correct value. Because you didn't assign any value to your properties. you have to assign value to properties are create full properties using local variables like following code. And use local variable as you mentions. when you will assign value to local variable or property you'll get that value other wise you'll get default value 0 every time.

```
 private int seconds, minutes, hours;

    public int Hours
    {
        get { return hours; }
        set { hours = value; }
    }

    public int Minutes
    {
        get { return minutes; }
        set { minutes = value; }
    }

    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return seconds; }
        set { seconds = value; }
    }
```